# Query builds failed because of timeout - Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020

In our dev environment we have lots of repos, lots of builds and lots of buildservers, and most of the time things work just like they should - however, we are seeing an increase in builds that fail because of timeouts.

These timeouts are not happening because we are getting close to the limit, but because something "gets stuck/blocked" in the pipeline and it stays on that step until timeout kills the build.

To better debug why that happens, we need to be able to query what builds fails because of this timeout, so we for instance can see, if it is a particular build server or agent that has this problem.

We can not find anything in the API that would give us the timeout error, but we can see that the UI is able to deduct it somehow:

[image: Screenshot of timeout]

So far we have narrowed it down to query all builds with completed status ([through this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)), but we get no completion reason, and buildtimes are never exact the same as the timeout of the build defintion, so "guessing" it from the execution plan will also be a bit shaky.

How can we filter our builds down to only the builds that have timed out?

Comment: Hi @Johny Skovdal, not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, please feel free to share it here.

Comment: Yes, I marked it as solved too. I do miss having an actual property to test, but that's not the case at the moment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the below [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get details for a build.

**Note**: do not add timelineId, we should list all info

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

If the build is canceled because of the timeout setting, we can get the message: `The job running on agent Hosted Agent ran longer than the maximum time of xxx minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134`

[image]

By the way, we can use the API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to filter all failed build. if the build is canceled due to a timeout setting. the result is failed instead of cancel.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! To add to the answer: I filtered by the following to get the record I needed - `Where-Object { $_.state -eq 'completed' -and ($_.type -eq 'Job') -and ($_.result -eq 'canceled')}`

Comment: My test data were incomplete. This of course gave me all canceled builds, including timeouts. I had to add the following test: `-and (($_.issues | Select-Object -first 1).message -match 'has exceeded the maximum execution time')`